# Overriding order_status_id variables in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

Currently using OpenCart for our e-commerce needs.

I am currently retrieving order status variables from an array that resides within `/upload/install/opencart.sql` where it contains a list of OpenCart order status variables called `order_status_id`

```
INSERT INTO `oc_order_status` (`order_status_id`, `language_id`, `name`) VALUES
(2, 1, 'Processing'),
(3, 1, 'Shipped'),
(7, 1, 'Canceled'),
(5, 1, 'Complete'),
(8, 1, 'Denied'),
(9, 1, 'Canceled Reversal'),
(10, 1, 'Failed'),
(11, 1, 'Refunded'),
(12, 1, 'Reversed'),
(13, 1, 'Chargeback'),
(1, 1, 'Pending'),
(16, 1, 'Voided'),
(15, 1, 'Processed'),
(14, 1, 'Expired');
```

I would like to override these variables, since our customer uses a different set of order statuses. I think it is against MVC principles to directly edit OpenCart's default variables, is that right? Anyways, I tried to edit this array, such as changing `Processing` to `Paying`, but the changes did not actually show up on the development site.

Am I looking at the wrong place? What is the right way to change these default OpenCart order status variable?

Comment: Oh boy, you are totally lost in OpenCart, PHP and MySQL, aren't you? Please, go check in the administration: System -> Localization -> Order statuses - here you can edit the statuses (string tokens) used for orders. The file you are referring to is used only for OpenCart installation - those values are inserted into the DB and afterwards this file is completely useless. You shouldn't be getting the order statuses from this file but from the DB, OMG!

Comment: Thanks @shadyyx once again :p

Comment: Just as an aside, you should really delete your `/install` folder after installing!

Comment: @shadyyx - You should convert your comment to an answer.  It is correct, and I would absolutely upvote it, since it helped me out when searching for something related!